# Turning a actionscript string with a url into a HTML link

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm retrieving an unformatted String from a twitter feed. I want to be able to turn a text URL (http://blah.com/qwerty/) into a link but don't know how...is there a handy regular expression for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var protocol:String = "((?:http://|https://|ftp://|www\.))";
var urlPart:String = "([a-z0-9\-.#&?%$/=*_]+)";
var urlPattern:RegExp = new RegExp(protocol + urlPart , "ig");

//TEXT.match(urlPattern).length>0
TEXT = TEXT.replace(urlPattern, "<a href='$1$2'><u>$1$2</u></a>");
TEXT = TEXT.split("<a href='www.").join("<a target='_blank' href='http://www.")
```

This should work. Make sure the textfield is selectable.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this before, but the docs specify a TextEvent called Link, which will detect when you click on a HTML hyperlink that is inside a TextField - as long as the TextField has had HTML enabled. Details on how to make a TextField HTML-enabled will be in the docs too, but the specific information about using [TextEvent.Link is here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html#event:link)

Hope that helps.

debu

Comment: Hi thanks but the problem is around actually making the text into HTML format. At the moment its just plain text, i need to find out a way to find out if the text is a link or not; then i can use the TextEvent...